# Распределённый сервер

Tags: c#, сервер, сокет, клиент-сервер, udp

Скажите пожалуйста, как сделать сервер, чтобы через него можно было отправлять картинку (stream) от одного клиента к другому? В принципе, можно запустить 10 программ с разными портами на 20 клиентов, но это костыль как мне кажется. :(

[image: 1]
P.S. Стрелочкой обозначено направление пересылки данных, от кого к кому.

Comment: Есть клиент 1, который через сервер отправляет клиенту 2 картинку, который в свою очередь ее получает. Вроде все предельно ясно или что-то я не до понимаю, сложность то в чем?

Comment: @sp7 а что если будет 150 клиентов, сервер же запутается если делать стандартным путём

Comment: Просто я не совсем понимаю как клиенты у вас будут друг с другом взаимодействовать. Судя по тому, что Вы нарисовали у Вас Клиент 1 будет отправлять клиенту 2 сообщение, а клиент 2 будет только его получать и все.  Или возможны какие-то другие сценарии, например, каждый клиент может отправлять сообщение другому?

Comment: @sp7 нет, вообщем пример : у меня на компе стоит серв, на четырёх ноутбуках стоит клиент, на любом из ноутбуков можно сделать сессию после чего вылезет ид сессии (для простоты коннекта) и ждёт коннекта какого-нибудь компа, когда второй комп-клиент вводит ид сессии высвеченного на первом ноуте и нажимает на кнопку "ок", то от первого ноута идёт нарисованная картинка (stream) до серва, а серв перекидывает картинку на второй ноутбук.

Comment: А почему для Ваших целей не использовать `RabbitMQ`, там есть такие механизмы как `Topics` и `Routing` в принципе их можно использовать в вашем контексте?

Answer (score 1):

> В принципе, можно запустить 10 программ с разными портами на 20
>   клиентов

Зачем? Можно использовать много поточность.
Создайте 1 поток слушатель, который при подключении клиента будет запускать другой специальный поток для работы с ним. При отключении этот поток уничтожается.

Также имеет смысл проработать формат передачи данных, чтобы данные передавались только между "нужными" клиентами.

Можно задействовать готовые решения для ESB. Некоторые обсуждались [на англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353/net-esbs-out-there).

В крайнем случае можно попробовать реализовать свой формат передачи. Но, глубоко сомневаюсь, что такое потребуется.

Comment: Вот то что я и хотел спросить "Также имеет смысл проработать формат передачи данных, чтобы данные передавались только между "нужными" клиентами.".

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, к сожалению, если проблема именно в этом очень сложно дать однозначный ответ. Можно задействовать готовые решения для ESB, В крайнем случае написать собственный формат обмена, если готовое не устроит. Но, в последнем я сильно сомневаюсь.

Comment: А какие есть решения?

Comment: Некоторые примеры можно посмотреть по ссылке, которую я добавил в ответ.

Comment: Чёто как то сложно. А нельзя просто создать list из класса в котором будут : ссылка на первый пк, ссылка на второй пк и ид сессии. А потом если на серв пойдёт stream то брать из класса который лежит в list противоположный компьютер и отправлять по ссылке на нужный комп полученный stream?

Comment: Здесь уже упомянутая реализация своего формата передачи данных. Если Вы считаете данный вариант более оптимальным, то почему бы нет?

Comment: Всё понятно, значит делаем своё. Подскажите мне пожалуйста тогда как гуглить, чтобы узнать как сделать чтобы приём и ответ мог работать одновременно с некоторым числом клиентов,, ну как-бы сетевую многопоточность?